# Radio button onclick bring div to highest zindex

Tags: javascript, html

**Background:**

So... first shot with radio buttons triggering onclick javascript function.

I have a collection of radio buttons (name = 'div_select') that i'm attempting to pair each button with a specific div ('beginner1', 'beginner2', etc.).  When the radio button is selected, I'm trying to set the zIndex of the paired div to be the highest via onclick.

Each of the paired divs are formatted via CSS so that they're all in the exact same location (`#beginner1, #beginner2, #adept1, etc. {}`).

At this point I'm attempting to make a different onclick for each pairing.

---

**Issue:**

I have not been having luck changing the zindex to bring the div to the foreground.

---

**Question:**

As I am fairly new to the html/javascript realm, the fairly blanket question would be "where am i going wrong?"

I have read through several posts (e.g., [bring div element to front with zIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731584/bring-div-element-to-front-with-zindex-in-react) and [set zIndex onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010865/javascript-set-z-index-on-click)) to try and make some headway on my own, but I feel my skills in these languages are so limited that I'm at a fairly utter loss to understand what tags to even use.

---

**Code in question**

```js
function highest_index() {
  var highest_index
  highest_index = highest_index +
}

function beg1() {
  document.getElementByID('beginner1').style.zIndex = highest_index;
}

function adt1() {
  document.getElementByID('adept1').style.zIndex = highest_index;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- 
    DOCK ON LEFT   
   -->
  <div id="dok">
    <div style="left: 0; width:100%;">
      <p style="font-size: 12px; padding: 0%,1%,0%,0%; font-weight: bold;">
        Beginner
      </p>
      <input type="radio" name="div_select" onclick="beg1()" />Video<br/>
      <hr/>
      <p style="font-size: 12px; padding: 0%,1%,0%,0%; font-weight: bold;">
        Adept
      </p>
      <input type="radio" name="div_select" onclick="adt1()" />Video<br/>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 
    OVERLAY BODY SECTIONS 
   -->
  <div id="beginner1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; width: 80%;">Label for Table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="adept1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>second div intended to test </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**Edit to javascript based on comments section:**

```js
var highest_index = highest_index++;
}
function beg1() {
   document.getElementByID('beginner1').style.zIndex = highest_index();
}
function adt1() {
   document.getElementByID('adept1').style.zIndex = highest_index();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, when I click "Run code snippet" it reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'", indicating it expected something after the `+` and did not find it.

Comment: @TylerRoper i just added `;` after the `+`... regarding the global variable, i appear to have tucked that into a `formula`, so i am thinking i can take it out and use `var highest_index = highest_index+;` to make it a counting global variable?

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks; `++` is what i was working towards... had originally wrote `+1;` and in removing the 1 (also looks like i took off the ;) didn't add in the other + and appropriately break the line.  This helps and I'll keep plugging away.  Will update question to show what i've done with that thusfar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are quite a few issues here but I'll address them individually.

1. Your `highest_index` variable should be declared globally so that it isn't reset each time the function is called.
2. Having a variable and a function with the same name in the same scope will cause conflict. Change the name of one or the other.
3. `highest_index+` should be `highest_index++`, or if you want to `return` the result at the same time you can use `++highest_index` (both increment `highest_index`, but `var++` returns the value *before* incrementing, whereas `++var` returns the value *after* incrementing).
4. As 3 points out, you want to `return` the updated `highest_index` so that you can use it.
5. `getElementByID` is not a function (JS is case-sensitive!). Change `ID` to `Id`.

Feel free to remove the `console.log()`s that I've added; they're solely for demo purposes.

I've added comments to the code below to highlight the changes above by number.

```js
var highest_index = 0;        //1. Highest index declared globally

function getHighestIndex() {  //2. Function renamed
  return ++highest_index;     //3 & 4. Increment and return
}

//5. GetElementByID changed to GetElementById
function beg1() {
  document.getElementById('beginner1').style.zIndex = getHighestIndex();
  console.log(`The z-index of beginner1 is ${document.getElementById('beginner1').style.zIndex}`);
}

//5. GetElementByID changed to GetElementById
function adt1() {
  document.getElementById('adept1').style.zIndex = getHighestIndex();
  console.log(`The z-index of adept1 is ${document.getElementById('adept1').style.zIndex}`);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- 
    DOCK ON LEFT   
   -->
  <div id="dok">
    <div style="left: 0; width:100%;">
      <p style="font-size: 12px; padding: 0%,1%,0%,0%; font-weight: bold;">
        Beginner
      </p>
      <input type="radio" name="div_select" onclick="beg1()" />Video<br/>
      <hr/>
      <p style="font-size: 12px; padding: 0%,1%,0%,0%; font-weight: bold;">
        Adept
      </p>
      <input type="radio" name="div_select" onclick="adt1()" />Video<br/>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 
    OVERLAY BODY SECTIONS 
   -->
  <div id="beginner1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; width: 80%;">Label for Table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="adept1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>second div intended to test </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping outline some of the glaring issues (saw your post comment, too).  Taking some time to read more as I'm implementing your input (e.g., `++var` versus `var++` and why).  Still getting the hang of Sharepoint Designer and some of the elements are not popping up as they should so have mistyped a bit (ID vs Id).  Edit:  Just saw you added explanation for what I was just looking into.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I've also edited my answer to explain the difference between `var++` vs `++var` in the event you hadn't seen that yet. For what it's worth, the pop-up suggestions are referred to as *code completion*, or you might often hear devs refer to them as *IntelliSense*, which is Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: Didn't realize it's the same for VBA calling it intellisense... trying to break my bad (but appropriate to that language) VBA habits is definitely enough of a challenge.  Will check back later as let you know if I can accept as answered... gotta play/test to get each div to move to foreground after fixing the javascript issues.

Comment: I don't seem to be having luck onclick with the radio buttons to change the zindex to bring each div to the foreground, even with the javascript changes.  At this point, the last div in the html is always on top.  I assume I have issues in my code, though I am wondering if there's a better approach (radio buttons just seemed to work so only one could be reviewed at a time).

Comment: Unfortunately you may have to provide more code so that we can replicate the behavior in your question, or if the issue is now unrelated to the JavaScript, ask a separate question rather than editing this one (and invalidating existing answers).

Comment: Understandable.  I thought I had posed this as a gross question, but given that this is essentially 3 different languages in tandem, you have helped resolve the javascript issue (based on the errors that did exist) so i can list this one as answered and be more HTML focused in the next.  Thanks, Tyler!

Comment: I think the question was broad enough to cover those, however given SO's policy that "questions should be as specific as possible", I figured breaking it out would be a better idea. So this one was essentially "Applying the next highest z-index to an element using javascript". Now that that's working, your next question might be something like "Layering items using z-index". The one thing I will say: **If  your items do not have `position` defined in CSS, they will not be affected by `z-index`.** Try applying `position: relative;` to the elements you're trying to layer if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip... i had absolute as position, will try relative.

Comment: @Cyril `absolute` will work as well, you just have to have *any* defined `position`. If you look at the elements in *Inspect Element*, do you see that the z-index is successfully being applied at least?

Comment: Not seeing it applied to the div.  Will post specific to the layering based on zIndex.